# Azure functions python VSCode Debug The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, azure-functions

When trying to debug my python azure function from Visual Studio code I get the error below

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the four json files in the `.vscode` folder?

Answer (score 0):

**Please make sure you have installed `virtualenv`, then you can debug your function app.**

*You can follow below article.*

[Installing packages using pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-packages-using-pip-and-virtual-environments)